# Хранить координаты разреженной матрицы в hash-таблице

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. Необходимо перемножить разреженные матрицы. Для этого координаты ненулевых элементов разреженной таблицы нужно хранить в хэш-таблице. Как это можно реализовать? Можно ли сделать так : 
**`values = new HashTable<Integer, new HashTable<Integer, Integer>>`**
где key тэйбла -- ненулевой элемент, value -- координаты

Comment: А не лучше создать класс с тремя свойствами(x,y,value) и поместить его в обычный Array, List или Set на выбор?

Comment: @rjhdby, и как искать значение по координатам? Полным перебором?

Comment: Ну вам же все равно придется всех их перебрать, чтоб перемножить? Но если надо по координатам искать, то лучше так `values = new HashMap<Pair<Integer,Integer>, Integer>` где Pair взять, например, из апачевских либ, либо сделать свой

Comment: Перебирать их придется в определенном порядке, а не абы как. Впрочем, [тут объясняется](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390181/sparse-matrices-arrays-in-java), почему `HashMap` вообще не лучший выбор для моделирования разреженных матриц. Да и вообще библиотеку  линейной алгебры для серьезных применений лучше брать готовую. При самостоятельной реализации есть риск много где напортачить.

Comment: я бы с радостью избежал использование мапы, но, увы, использовать hash-таблицу -- один из пунктов тз в вузе

Comment: Тогда, как предлагает @rjhdby, просто используйте в мапе в качестве ключа `Pair.of(x,y)` из Apache Commons или напишите свой класс, напрмимер `Coords` с `final` полями `x` и `y` и правильными `hashCode()` и `equals()`.

Comment: @Nofate благодарю

Answer (score 1):

Стандартное перемножение разреженных матриц в формате CSR с разъяснениями: https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/d/4/1/d/8/LW_SparseMM_ppt.pdf
Правда, придётся переводить с несложного С++.
Но если нужно не просто проиллюстрировать алгоритм, а чтобы он работал быстро с огромными матрицами, лучше обойтись без самописного кода, веороятно даже C-шные библиотеки подключать...